# finds records in a collection that contains all values in a given array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

is there a function in mongodb that finds records in a collection that contains all values in a given array?
ex:
i have a collection called channels,
the collection has a field called fields. The field fields contains an array of objects.
example:

```
{
  _id: "1advs23rfwdfsd23r32r2wf89UJ*ADJ8j10u9u1-2u3",
  fields:[
     {
      "field_name": "first_name"
     },
     {
      "field_name": "last_name"
     },
    ]
 }
```

is there a function that can find all the Channels that contain a certain set of fields?
example:
find all the channels that contain the fields :"first_name", "last_name", "state".

I tried the following but it didnt work

```
Channel.find({ fields: { $all: [{ "field_name": "state" },{ "field_name": "last_name" },{ "field_name": "first_name" }] } })
```

Comment: Looks fine. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J_xqIZ1DUzB) With `$all` the document needs to fulfill every element in the input array. But if you look for match any element, then you should use `$in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$in`

It is used to select documents in which the field's value equals any of the given values in the array

and `$all` will work only if all the values match the values of an array field in a document

```js
Channel.find({ fields: { $in: [{ "field_name": "state" },{ "field_name": "last_name" },{ "field_name": "first_name" }] } })
```